# How to store user input into a list in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to be able to take input from a user (store it in a list) and and print it to the screen to prove it was stored in a list or print #f if the list contains an element that is not a number. The idea is to then use the result of that function in another that will give me the sum (I've already made that function). I have been looking all over and can not find any information on how to do this in Scheme. I know let has to be used, but I am not sure how I would implement it.

(read-user-ints)

=>1

=>2

=>3

=>4

=>5

=>e

(1 2 3 4 5)

Comment: `(define (read-user-ints) (sequence->list (in-producer read (negate number?))))`

Answer (score 1):

start with defining e to be the empty list.

```
(define e '())
```

then you can use a recursive loop with READ to get ints, each time you get one you can append it onto the end of your list like this:

```
(set! e (append e (list number)))
```

If you were struggling with the LET part, you can do something like this

```
(let loop ((number (read)))
    ;; check if number is actually a number or if it's 'e'
    ;; either append it or exit the loop (by not calling loop)
    )
```

---

Answering your follow up comment.

You can use BEGIN to put multiple statements in one branch of an IF expression, like this:

```
(define read-int-list
  (lambda ()
    (let loop ((number (read)))
      (if (number? number)
          (begin (set! e (append e (list number)))
                 (loop))
          'done
          ))))
```

Comment: This takes quadratic time, right? To get linear time, you can `cons` the new elements to the front, and then `reverse` them all at once when the character e is read.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase if you'd like to ask about this as a separate question I will show you efficient techniques

Comment: (define read-int-list
  (lambda()
    (let loop ((number (read)))
    (if (number? number) 
        (set! e (append e (list number)))
    ))))             How do I get this to loop? currently it only allows one input then exits

Comment: @AlexSam added info about this to the answer